# Can I get git not to merge files, but simply copy newever ones

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to prevent the line-by-line merging of certain files in git. In my project I have a few directories which contain files produced by some other project. These files need to be a part of this repository, but they are not to be editted in here.  That is, any replacement is complete and no partial merge/resolution should be attempted.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at submodules instead?

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I want. The files don't really belog to a nice module, they are more of a finished product than actual source. Plus anybody working on the project definitely needs these files (it isn't optional).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `.gitattributes` file in the root of the project (or individual files in the directories in question) as follows:

```
path/to/my/file merge=theirs
```

or, for multiple files matching a pattern:

```
path/to/dir/*.ext merge=theirs
```

This will tell Git to resolve any merge conflicts by taking the incoming version.

Comment: Is there some way to check the date as well? It'd be nice to take whichever version is newest.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell: you’d need to write your own merge driver (see [the gitattributes man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitattributes), under the section “Definining a custom merge driver”), but even then I’m not sure you’d have access to the commit timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use [git attributes](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitattributes) to mark the files as binary and no suitable for merge. Depending upon the attributes you give you can get git to avoid trying merges for binary types (eg: *.dat binary). You may also want to try the merge strategies 'ours' and 'theirs'. Not having done this myself I'm not certain of the effects but I think this is the area you should be looking at.